# How to utter the input text as output (respnse) in rasa core?

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core

Example-

Input -> My name is XYZ

Output -> My name is XYZ

I want this to happen for every input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [custom actions](https://rasa.com/docs/core/customactions/#custom-actions) to accomplish this behaviour. Should this only happen for certain intents or in general? 
Story would look like:

```
 * intent_whose_message_should_be_mirrored
   - action_respond_with_user_message
```

And the like:

```
class ActionRespondWithUserMessage(Action):
   def name(self):
      return "action_respond_with_user_message"

   def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
      last_message = tracker.latest_message.get("text", "")
      dispatcher.utter_message(last_message)

      return []
```